# Input-Output transformation remove nodes and update nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How to translate the given input xml into the output as shown below.
The input xml should be transformed by removing the wsse:Security header completely and EventUser value must be updated with the Username node value.
I tried below xlst. It is not working

XLST -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="EventUser">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="Username"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security mustUnderstandValue="1"
                     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken id="UsernameToken-274">
            <wsse:Username>MyUsername</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis2ns682:Create xmlns:axis2ns682="http://g22.test01.org/test02/RF">
         <tns:CreateDetails xmlns:tns="http://g22.test01.org/test02/RF">
            <tns:EventUser>Event</tns:EventUser>
            <tns:PreApprovedTemplateID>221398</tns:PreApprovedTemplateID>
            <tns:Priority>High</tns:Priority>
            <tns:PlannedImplementation_Start>2017-09-29</tns:PlannedImplementation_Start>
         </tns:CreateDetails>
      </axis2ns682:Create>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Output -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>      
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis2ns682:Create xmlns:axis2ns682="http://g22.test01.org/test02/RF">
         <tns:CreateDetails xmlns:tns="http://g22.test01.org/test02/RF">
            <tns:EventUser>MyUsername</tns:EventUser>
            <tns:PreApprovedTemplateID>221398</tns:PreApprovedTemplateID>
            <tns:Priority>High</tns:Priority>
            <tns:PlannedImplementation_Start>2017-09-29</tns:PlannedImplementation_Start>
         </tns:CreateDetails>
      </axis2ns682:Create>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems with your XSLT

1. You have not accounted for namespaces in your XSLT. In your XML, the elements are in various namespaces (the `EventUser` element is in namespace `http://g22.test01.org/test02/RF` as denoted by the `tns:` prefix.
2. You have not coded anything to remove the `wsse:Security` element
3. The template matching `EventUser` is selecting `Username`, which would only would if `Username` was a child of `EventUser`. You actually need to select it from the soap:Header

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:tns="http://g22.test01.org/test02/RF"
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="wsse:Security" />

    <xsl:template match="tns:EventUser">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="//soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Username"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```